# Getting an error message when running a script in Cooja

Tags: user-interface, visualization, iot, contiki, cooja

I'm trying to code the simulation script editor to calculate end-to-end delay and so on, but after the simulation is finished, I encounter the following message:

TEST TIMEOUT

TEST FAILED [if test was run without visualization, Cooja would now have been terminated]

If anyone can point me in the right direct, I would appreciate the help.